# Are there dedicated folders for user made sources and libraries/modules?

Tags: directory, development

This is a very basic question, yet I can't find anything relevant. Is there a standard directory where to put the sources of your projects and the location of the libraries/modules they use (which are made for the project and are non standard) ?

Comment: Not that I'd know of. Since those files belong to a single user, they should reside within that users home folder, and there the user has complete freedom regarding file hierarchy. Of course you can put files in $HOME/lib and $HOME/include, but afaik those folders are not treated in any special way, and since you probably want to keep different development projects separate from each other, it's probably better to make separate subfolders for each project. However the $HOME/bin folder is special on Debian based distributions, since it is added to $PATH by default (if it exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you put the sources wherever you want.

If you plan to distribute your project via binary packages or repository, you should think in integrating it with the normal filesystem structure (i.e. binaries in `/usr/bin`, libraries in `/usr/lib`, data files in `/usr/share`...).

If the users are supposed to compile themselves the program, it (was?) an honored Unix tradition to install the project under `/usr/local` (`/usr/local/bin`,  `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/share`)...

There are some "standards' which are more or less followed: the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/fhs), or somewhere in the [Freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/) pages (e.g [XDG Base Directory Specification)](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/).

Comment: @Bloodcount: Don't forget to upvote too (^)

Comment: @SylvainPineau thanks --- I am sure that there is a filesystem hierarchy standard for applications on freedesktop.org (.desktop files, configuration etc) but I could not find it. Feel free to edit the link if you are more successful...